# Spotfire - Change data path without replacing data table

Tags: tibco, spotfire

Is it possible to edit the path name of a data table so that it is now `S\:DocumentName.xlsx` and instead is a relative server path such as `\\ServerName\:DocumentName.xlsx`? I'd like to do this without using Replace Data Table because I have too many inserted and calculated columns on the table I want to change paths.

Thank you,

Chris

Comment: Replacing data table to a new one with the same structure doesn't affect calculations and visualisations, replace data table is the solution for you.

Comment: There isn't a script or any way to change the first part of the file path? If I replace the data table then calculated columns I've made will not work when some field names have been changed, plus I'll have to "insert column" for all inserted columns on the current data table (I'm trying to avoid this as there are over 20 inserted columns).

Comment: Even if there would be a way for that, when you load the new data you still would have lose the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your file and spotfire will prompt for its location if, for some reason, you don't want to use the replace data table but it will be the same result as replacing data table.

Comment: PERFECT! This is a great work-around. Thank you so much.

Comment: I can't believe there isn't a better solution than this one. Suppose you aren't able to rename the file. You'd have to add all of the columns again. What's worse is when you add columns from another table, the Source Information tab in Data Table Properties doesn't tell you what columns you've actually added--just what columns were matched.

Answer (score 0):

Edit > Data Table Properties > Refresh Data (with prompt)

Comment: This doesn't allow me to specify file paths. Using Spotfire 6.5.3, so I don't know if that matters.

Comment: The windows file browse dialog should appear.

Comment: It takes me straight to the Import Settings window, the same one that opens when I select a file to add as a new data table. Again, it might be because I'm using 6.5.3.

Comment: I haven't got Spotfire installed anymore so I can't check but I remember using this many times from there. You may need to check import settings before changing file path. This is on 6.5 too.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Replace Data table. And then follow the instruction in appeared window.